# Intellij Extract Inner Class

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, refactoring, inner-classes

How does one who is using IntelliJ or Android Studio extract a public static inner class to create a new top level class?

Thank you.

Comment: Excuse the wordiness. The question was too short initially. Basically: How do I extract a public static inner class to create a new top level class in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Select the class name.

`Refactor > Move` or press `F6`

Select "Move inner class Foo to upper level"

Comment: Is there a way to move all inner classes at once?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: One thing to note: this has to be done from the code editor window. It doesn't work if you select the nested class in the Structure view and refactor from there (2016.3.4).